What is the connection between Renfield and vampirism?
In Dracula, in order to gain access to Dr. Seward's asylum (and Mina Harker), the Count bribes Renfield, Dr. Seward's "zoophagous" patient, into inviting him into the building (as he can't enter a building without first being invited_:

Renfield proceeded:—
“He came up to the window in the mist, as I had seen him often before; but he was solid then—not a ghost, and his eyes were fierce like a man’s when angry. He was laughing with his red mouth; the sharp white teeth glinted in the moonlight when he turned to look back over the belt of trees, to where the dogs were barking. I wouldn’t ask him to come in at first, though I knew he wanted to—just as he had wanted all along. Then he began promising me things—not in words but by doing them.” He was interrupted by a word from the Professor:—
“How?”
“By making them happen; just as he used to send in the flies when the sun was shining. Great big fat ones with steel and sapphire on their wings; and big moths, in the night, with skull and cross-bones on their backs.” Van Helsing nodded to him as he whispered to me unconsciously:—
“The Acherontia Aitetropos of the Sphinges—what you call the ‘Death’s-head Moth’?” The patient went on without stopping.
Dracula (1897), by Bram Stoker, chapter 21, Project Gutenburg version

How did Dracula know to find Renfield in particular? Renfield always seemed to be a sort of vampire-wannabe, in a sense; instead of feeding on human blood, he would eat his flies and spiders etc. alive in order to consume their life force. However, he doesn't seem to have had any previous connection with a vampire, the Count or otherwise, so it's unclear how he developed his zoophagous habits and what connection that has to vampires.
Do Renfield's culinary habits have any other connection to vampirism? What is the significance of Renfield's life-consumption compared to the Count's?
